# How to handle both args4j options and Java opts?

Tags: java, args4j

I am using args4j in order to process my options that I will pass as parameter to the program. I also want to increase the heap size. So that I would like to run something like:

```
> hadoop jar hadoop-program.jar -i /input/directory -o /output/directory -Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx10G
```

Obviously, I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException:
>   "-Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx10G" is not a valid option

Could someone please tell me how to handle this.

Comment: What is with `hadoop jar -Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx10G hadoop-program.jar -i /input/directory -o /output/directory` ?

Comment: @PeterMmm in that way I will get an issue like: "Not a valid JAR: -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts"